# How to create an instance with the name from a string

Tags: java, string, class

So, I need an Instance on my class company. That's easy

```
public Company company1 = new Company();
```

Well, how do you create an instance with the name from a string like

```
public String companyName = "Google"
public Company [the companyName String as.. thisthing] = new Company();`
```

or something... or something...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create class instance by string name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185661/how-to-create-class-instance-by-string-name)

Comment: Objects / instances don't have names. Variables do. Those variable names are statically known at *compile-time*. You probably want a `Map<String, Company>`

Comment: Does the `Company` class have a constructor that takes a `String`? If not, does it have a method that allows you to set a `String` variable belonging to a given instance of `Company`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put your objects in an `ArrayList` to access them all, not try to name them by a string value